# bx slider gotoslide from other page link

Tags: slider, bxslider, goto

I try to jump directly to a slide of my bx slider through a link from another page. For example - on page1.html there is a link to slide 7 of the slider on page2.html. How can I control the gotoslide function from an external page?

Answer (score 1):

for all those who were searching for the same thing. My solution for now: 
in the page where the slider is situated:

`var startingSlide=document.URL.substring(document.URL.lastIndexOf('?')+1)-1;`
 and make 
`startSlide: startingSlide` instead of a slide number.

The link from the other page to a specific slide is like this:

`<a href="slidersite.html?5">specific slide</a>` if you want to got to slide 5.

Don't know if that's the best way, but it works.